# Google Maps and Play Service 6.1.09

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

My app uses a `Runnable` to display animated weather radar overlay onto Google Maps using an `ArrayList<TileOverlay>`.

I haven't touched that code in weeks, I haven't updated my app in weeks. 3-4 days ago, the radar animation quit working on some devices. After some testing and checking with my beta testers, I figured out that the animation works fine on devices that have Google Play Services 5.0.89 installed. But it does not work with devices that have version 6.1.09 installed.

Then I checked Google Play store to see what version of Play Service is listed there. The page was last updated Sep 26 2014 and shows Version 5.0.89, not 6.1.09 (even though the official announcement was made many days before that http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/09/google-play-services-61.html).

I'd like to know if others are seeing issues/bugs with 6.1.09 in their apps. 
I'd like to know if 6.x is even official right now given 5.x is listed in Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue ! 
My app have not changed for weeks, and suddenly it did not work anymore.

What I've found:

1) by clicking on the map, the layer is refreshed
2) With a clearcache() every frame it works because it forces the map to be redraw. But it's not a solution, this cause a lot of of flickering.

This seems to be a refresh problem with the new version of Google Play Services 6.1.09

Have you found a workaround ?

An issue exists:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7185

Comment: Yeah, I submitted that bug. Play Services is now up to 6.1.11, but  it does not look like that bug was fixed in it. I have not yet found a solution.

Comment: Yes indeed same problem with 6.1.11, but there is a response from Google: Thank you for the reports. The bug has been fixed and will be available in the next release of Google Play services.

I don't have any timing to report for that just yet, though. Please star this issue to get updates.

Comment: If you can't wait for the fix, doing this after each frame forces an update.  `map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0.01f, 0));`